# Formulation of total variation measure of Banach space-valued measures

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

**Disclaimer**: the question is rather imprecise, so suggestions to improve it/correct it are warmly welcome.

Given a measure $\mu$ valued in a normed Banach space $(B,|\cdot|_B)$, say $\mu\in\mathcal{M}(\Omega;B)$ (where for the scope of this question we can assume $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ compact), we can define its *total variation measure* as
\begin{align}\label{eq} |\mu|(E) := {\sup \left\{ ~ \sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}|\mu(E_i)|_B ~~ | ~~ \{E_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}} \text{ partition of } E ~ \right\}}
\end{align}

Now, if $B = (\mathbb{R}^n, ||\cdot||_p)$, with $p\in[1,+\infty]$, then we can exploit the duality between the $p-$ and the $q-$norm (with the usual relation $\tfrac{1}{p}+\tfrac{1}{q}=1$), i.e.

$$ ||x||_p = {\sup_{||y||_q \le 1} y \cdot x} $$

and find that

$$ |\mu|_p(E) = {\sup \left\{ \int_\Omega \varphi(x)\cdot d\mu(x) ~~ | ~~ \varphi\in C^\infty_c(E;\mathbb{R}^n), \ ||\varphi(x)||_q\le1 \right\}} $$

(I actually don't know if this is precisely reported, especially the space of test functions, and I am not sure how to make sense of this "integral of a scalar product between a function and a measure", but I had seen it done in a similar fashion; references to this topic are again warmly welcome).

**My question is**: how do we generalize this last fact to the case of $\mu\in\mathcal{M}(\Omega,B)$?

In particular, given a norm, do I choose the *dual* or the *predual* norm to test it? Clearly, in the finite-dimensional case, it makes no difference, as for each $p\in[0,+\infty]$, $(\mathbb{R}^n,||\cdot||_p)$ is reflexive, but what about the case of the codomain a general Banach space?

**My attempts**: I would have two natural generalizations (one of which only works if $B$ admits a predual, which I'll denote as $((^*B), |||\cdot|||)$, i.e. $(^*B)^* = B$; moreover I am denoting the dual of $B$ with $B^* = (B^*, ||\cdot||_*)$):

- $$ |\mu|(E) := { \sup\left\{ \int_\Omega < d\mu(x), \varphi(x) > ~~ | ~~ \varphi:E\to(^*B), ~ |||\varphi(x)||| \le 1 \right\} }$$
- $$ |\mu|(E) := { \sup\left\{ \int_\Omega < \psi(x), d\mu(x) > ~~ | ~~ \psi:E\to B^*, ~ ||\psi(x)||_* \le 1 \right\} }$$

however, I don't know again how to make sense of them, and which one (if any) to choose in order to generalize the finite-dimensional case. Any hint would be very appreciated!

Comment: I have only read parts of it in the past but if I recall correctly *Vector measures* by Diesel and Uhl should be a fairly good reference concerning, well, vector measures, maybe you'll find answers in that book.